# pcl error by trying to get the ti_mmwave_rospkg driver

Tags: ros, driver, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently trying to get the ti_mmwave_rospkg driver to run on my system (Ubuntu 20.04) so I can use the IWR6843ISK in ROS (noetic).

The problem I have is that after downloading the driver as described in the instructions (https://dev.ti.com/tirex/explore/node?devtools=IWR6843ISK&node=AOVWxEvg-HcESecamNaaLg__VLyFKFf__LATEST&search=IWR6843), when I run catkin_make in the terminal, I get errors spit out regarding the pcl library.

The following errors are just a sample:

```
 ...
    
    /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/PolygonMesh.h:55:24:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:4337:24: error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::PolygonMesh::concatenate(pcl::PolygonMesh&, const pcl::PolygonMesh&)::<lambda(int)>) (const pcl::Vertices&)’
     4337 |  *__result = __unary_op(*__first);
          |              ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
    
    ...
    
    /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_numeric.h:166:22: error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::getFieldsList(const pcl::PCLPointCloud2&)::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>) (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, const pcl::PCLPointField&)’
      166 |  __init = __binary_op(_GLIBCXX_MOVE_IF_20(__init), *__first);
          |           ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    ...
    
    /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/conversions.h:318:93:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::toPCLPointCloud2(const pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, pcl::PCLImage&)::<lambda(const int&)>) (const pcl::PCLPointField&)’
      283 |  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
          |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    ...
    
    /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/io.h:65:77:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::getFieldIndex(const pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, const string&)::<lambda(int)>) (const pcl::PCLPointField&)’
      283 |  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
          |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ...
    
    /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/conversions.h:318:93:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::toPCLPointCloud2(const pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, pcl::PCLImage&)::<lambda(const int&)>) (const pcl::PCLPointField&)’
      283 |  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
          |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    ...
    
    /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/io.h:65:77:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: no match for call to ‘(pcl::getFieldIndex(const pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, const string&)::<lambda(int)>) (const pcl::PCLPointField&)’
      283 |  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
          |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    ...
```

I know the instructions are actually designed for Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS melodic, but still thought this would not cause problems for newer versions.
I hope someone has an idea or even had the same problem and can help me with the pcl library to get the driver running on the current system.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376170/pcl-error-by-trying-to-get-the-ti_mmwave_rospkg-driver/) by [sanktu](https://answers.ros.org/users/73316/sanktu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve the problem myself.
The first error in the terminal at the top is:

```
#error PCL requires C++14 or above
```

I googled again and was able to solve the error with the help of this forum entry:
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/3104.

The CMakeList.txt must be extended by 2 commands so that the appropriate C++ version is used.

---

Originally posted by [sanktu](https://answers.ros.org/users/73316/sanktu/) with karma: 16 on 2021-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0